# Azure Single Sign On

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

If I need to establish SSO using Azure AD and my on premises Active Directory. I understand that I need:

1. AD FS (But I don't understand exactly where this can reside ... is it a service installed on premises?)
2. Azure AD Connect with password sync. This one is clear that stays on premises.
3. Password writeback for Azure AD ?? (not sure that I need this but in this case I know that I need Azure AD Premium)

Can someone direct me with further explanations / details?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. not necessary on premises, but makes most sense there. generally it needs access to your domain controllers over LDAP, so you could put it into Azure and create a site-to-site VPN (or express route) and it would work, but makes little sense. better on premises.
2. Again, you could put it in Azure, but that makes little sense. Password sync isn't needed if you are using AD FS. This can only help if your AD FS died and you disable AD FS temporary so you users can work while AD FS is down, but again, makes little sense with AD FS as all the authentication happens (when everything operates as it should) on your domain controllers.
3. Password Writeback, which just allows you to reset the password in Azure AD, and it'll get synced back to on-prem AD (by juunas)

Comment: sorry, I confused write-back with password sync, updated answer

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, you will need to configure Azure AD Connect on a machine that is domain-joined (on-prem or otherwise). But then you have some options.

If you don't want passwords to be synced to Azure AD, you can install ADFS in on-premises (or Azure with VPN) and set up federation between Azure AD and ADFS. Then your users will get redirected to sign in with ADFS when trying to sign in at Azure AD.

Another option is Password Sync, which will synchronize the password hashes from on-prem to Azure AD. This will allow your users to type in their password on the Azure AD login page. You don't need ADFS in this case.

Additionally you can enable Password Writeback, which just allows you to reset the password in Azure AD, and it'll get synced back to on-prem AD. Otherwise the sync is one-way only, and you can only reset passwords in on-prem AD.

Nowadays another option is also Pass-through authentication. This also allows your users to enter their passwords on the Azure AD login page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-sso-quick-start

Comment: Ahh did you mean Azure AD Connect? That's actually true! It just needs to be a domain-joined machine.